# Vue Vuetify. v-model for v-checkbox not taking the correct value when inside a v-for loop

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, v-for, v-model

So I have this in my template:

```
 <v-checkbox v-for="(option,index) in options" :key="option.id" :label="option.checked.toString()" :v-model="options[index].checked"></v-checkbox>
```

And this in my data():

```
options: [
        {
          id: '1',
          name: 'Cotton',
          checked : true
        },
        {
          id: '2',
          name: 'Silk',
          checked : false
        }
 ]
```

However, even when the value is true, the checkbox is not checked; why??

I have this in codepen:

https://codepen.io/averied/pen/JjYQLJQ?editable=true&editors=101%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fvuetifyjs.com%2Fen%2Fcomponents%2Fselection-controls%2F

Comment: Delete `:` before `v-model`

Comment: Honestly, when my eyes hurt after long hours of screen time, I thank the universe for having my friends at stackoverflow. What a blessing! Sorry for that @AdamOrlov

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete `:` before `v-model`

Plus
it would be cleaner to use

`v-model="option.checked"`

instead of `v-model="options[index].checked"`

then you do not need `index` in `v-for`

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `:` before `v-model`.